# How to prevent CSS code duplication inside media queries?

Tags: css

I am trying to develop my own grid system. This is my first attempt so maybe I am missing something. Here is my CSS:

```
.column-1 {
  width: 6.86666666667%;
}

.column-2 {
  width: 15.3333333333%;
}

// More such columns

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .column-s-1 {
    width: 6.86666666667%;
  }
  .column-s-2 {
    width: 15.3333333333%;
  }
}
```

As you can see the values are duplicated but class names are different. Is there any way I can avoid this duplication because it will become more and more complex with each additional class.

Comment: If you're willing to use a CSS preprocessor, it will make implementing a grid a lot easier for you. Here's an [example](http://www.sitepoint.com/creative-grid-system-sass-calc/)

Comment: But to answer your question directly, I don't see why you can't simply use the same class if it results in the same values.

Comment: I would like it to have different width at different sizes sort of like Bootstrap. If someone uses `column-4 column-s-6` on same element. Then, the element will have different  width based on screen size.

Comment: I see. You could probably use a @mixin again if you're using a CSS preprocessor otherwise I think you have to do it manually (i.e., duplicate).

Comment: You can't avoid this duplication in the CSS sent to the browser (the one you're writing or the one generated by a preprocessor). It should be gzipped efficiently though (but not certain). You'll be able to do it with CSS "variables" (custom properties) but [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) is very recent for Safari and is lacking in IE/Edge

Comment: use same class names and use post-css

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid some of duplication by grouping selectors:

```
.column-1,
.column-s-1 {
  width: 6.86666666667%;
}

.column-2,
.column-s-2 {
  width: 15.3333333333%;
}

// More such columns
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .column-s-1 {
    /* only properties characteristic for this width*/
  }
}
```

Another option is to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)